# How to display Time only from getCalendar()

Tags: java, android, date, datetime

I'm trying to add the offset of one timezone to another, which is stored in hourDifference. It works fine. However, I want to only output HH:MM not the full date as shown below, and store in new variable

1. Before: Thur Jan 01 **16:55**:00 GMT+00:00 1970
2. After Thur Jan 01 **17:55**:00 GMT+00:00 1970 (great it works)

What output i'd like: **17:55**

**My Code:**

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
//Mailer is a simple string in the format 16:55 PM for example
Date date = sdf.parse(mailer);
sdf.getCalendar().add(Calendar.HOUR, (int) **hourDifference**);

Log.d("Time with difference ", "LOG" + **sdf.getCalendar().getTime()**);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to format the output also:

```
sdf.format(date)
```

// EDIT per comments, to clarify

Here's a working example, from start to finish:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
try {
  Date date = sdf.parse(mailer);
  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
  calendar.setTime(date);
  calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, hourDifference);
  String formatted = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
  System.out.println(formatted);
} catch(Exception e){
  System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

So let's break this down line by line.

Here, you're creating an object with functionality for converting dates to human-readable strings, and vice versa:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
```

Here, you're creating a date from a string.  You need to use the formatter to do it, because the string is going to be in the "hh:mm" format you listed above.  If you had used a different formatter, it could very well misunderstand what date the string (mailer) signifies:

```
Date date = sdf.parse(mailer);
```

Here you're going to get a calendar instance, which has methods to modify the moment, unlike the Date class

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
```

Now set the calendar time to the date you got from your `mailer` string:

```
calendar.setTime(date);
```

Now modify the date by adding hours:

```
calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, hourDifference);
```

So at this point, both `date` and `calendar` are just instances of classes representing a moment in time.  The closest human-readable output you'd get normally is the number of milliseconds since the epoch.  You need to format it again to get it readable in the way you want, using the same formatter instance you created originally, just on the output side this time.  To do that, you'll need to supply the formatter the moment you're talking about, now best represented by the calendar instance (which had hours added to it).  Unfortunately, while you can pass a `Date` instance to `format`, you can't pass a `Calendar` instance, but you can pass the UTC time to represent the moment:

```
String formatted = sdf.format(calendar.getTime())
```

Note that the line above *returns* a string, which you can print out or log or whatever, but it does not actually transform the moment represented by the calendar instance.

HTH

Comment: I tired that i get the same result

Comment: When I use  sdf.getCalendar().getTime()); , the hourDifference is applied, when i use sdf.format(date) i only get the original time. I require the time to be added and then outputted. thanks momo

Comment: right, you'd have to add the time difference to the instance you're formatting

Comment: check the edits, should explain things pretty clearly